# a problem in updating todo in svelte todo app. using "store"

Tags: svelte

I did a basic Todo app with a svelte store.
In general, it works, but when I want to update Todo - it works for the first time, don't work after this.

If I update another Todo, the first could be updated again.
I try to find how to fix it, and I don't know.
(I see there is a problem with my `updatedId` variable)

here is my code :
in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vyqdn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K. I got it.
the problem was that i added in the custom store other pairs of "key-value" which are not connected to the regular store.
their value isn't updated reactively !!!
if in some values in the custom store there aren't the store methods (set , update , subscribe) , they shouldn't be there !
that was the mistake , the lines with the comments:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import uuid from 'uuid/v4'    

const todos_ = writable([]);


const customTodos={
    subscribe: todos_.subscribe,
    addTodo: (text)=>todos_.update(todos=>[...todos,{text,id:uuid()}]),
    deleteTodo: (id)=>todos_.update(todos=>todos.filter(todo=>todo.id!==id)),
    // updating:false,
    editTodo:(id,editedText)=>todos_.update(todos=>
        todos.map(todo=>todo.id===id ? {...todo,text:editedText}:todo)
    ),
    // updatedId:""
}

export default customTodos
```

what i should do is one from two options :

1. to create another two separate stores , and put that variables in them.
   so in every change of them the Dom updates too. that stores are like "global variables" [link to that solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/vyqdn)
2. more "elegant" way : to do inside all todo object another key of "editing" with the value false , and put a function in the store which change it. [link to that better solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-store-all-tuhjq)

Comment: I recommend looking at this to-do example. Using firestore, RxJs and stores it becomes  magic. Not familiar with this stuff and a beginner with Svelte-3 I was blown away. All in a few lines of code. This is a realtime experience in optima forma. https://fireship.io/lessons/svelte-v3-overview-firebase/

Comment: thanks on your comment i know to do that without stores , it's very easy.
 !my purpose was to practice stores and understand how to work with them.

Comment: The example I showed you is full of store magic. And interfaces with RxJS for even more magic.